# $x$ is a non-negative integer and $\sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x + 1}}$ is a positive integer.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find non-negative integer $x$ such that $\sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x + 1}}$ is a positive integer.

Because $\sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x + 1}} > x$, we let $x^2 + \sqrt{x + 1} = (x + y)^2, (y > 0)$

That means $$\begin{aligned}
&x^2 + \sqrt{x + 1} = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy\\
&\implies \sqrt{x + 1} = y^2 + 2xy\\
&\implies x + 1 = y^4 + 4x^2y^2 + 4xy^3
\end{aligned}$$

And this is where I was stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

For $x>0,$

$$x^2 < x^2+\sqrt{x+1} < (x+1)^2,$$

so there's no solution besides $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x = 0$ then $\sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x + 1}} = 1$.

If $x > 0$ then let $y = \sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x + 1}} > \left\{
\begin{aligned}
x &\implies (x - y)^2 > 0\\
1 &\implies x + y > x + 1
\end{aligned}
\right.$.

We have that $$\begin{aligned}
y &= \sqrt{x^2 + \sqrt{x + 1}}\\
\implies y^2 &= x^2 + \sqrt{x + 1}\\
\implies y^2 - x^2 &= \sqrt{x + 1}\\
\implies (y - x)(y + x) &= \sqrt{x + 1}\\
\implies (x - y)^2(x + y)^2 &= x + 1\\
\end{aligned}$$

That means $x + 1$ is divisible by $x + y$, contradicts $x + y > x + 1$.